# textContent not changing actual content but works on console.log

Tags: javascript

Im setting the text content of linkOutsideScreen[4] to be set to the itemAfterCorrespondingIndex.title. The new textContent is logged correctly to the console but the element that shows up on the screen does not have the correct and new textContent.

To further explain, I'm making a wheel that is hidden halfway on the right side of the screen. I start of by having 5 divs with a class "text" - from top to bottom it takes this order: Link 9, Link 10, Link 1, Link 2 and Link 3.

Here, the itemAfterCorrespondingIndex variable should be Link 4 (on the bottom side) because it is the next one entering the screen if I rotate the wheel clockwise. If i rotate counter clockwise, the itemBeforeCorrespondingIndex should be Link 8, which is the next one entering the screen, and so on.
I divided the "halfs" in linkOutsideScreen and linkInsideScreen (they both have 5 indexes).
Both the itemAfterCorrespondingIndex and itemBeforeCorrespondingIndex fetch data from a JSON file that has 50 entries that look like this: "title: Link 1", etc.
My goal here is to, when rotating clockwise, change the linkOutsideScreen[4] to the itemAfterCorrespondingIndex dinamically.
The console.log does change that index linkOutsideScreen[4], but the actual div doesnt get updated.
This is easier to understand if you place the "link 10" on the linkInsideScreen[4].
I also placed a text on the side that also changes correctly for easier visualization.

When the page first loads, all div's get populated with the possible entries in a numerical order.

I dont know what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
const palette = document.querySelector(".palette");
const rotateClockwiseBtn = document.getElementById("rotateClockwise");
const rotateAntiClockwiseBtn = document.getElementById("rotateAntiClockwise");
let rotationAngle = 0;
let dataArray = [];

rotateClockwiseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  rotationAngle += 36;
  updatePaletteRotation();
  setTimeout(() => {
    checkLinksVisibility();
  }, 200);
});

rotateAntiClockwiseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  rotationAngle -= 36;
  updatePaletteRotation();
  setTimeout(() => {
    checkLinksVisibility();
  }, 200);
});

function updatePaletteRotation() {
  palette.style.transform = `rotate(${rotationAngle}deg)`;
}

function checkLinksVisibility() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".palette a");
  const linksInsideScreen = [];
  const linksOutsideScreen = [];

  links.forEach((link) => {
    const rect = link.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (rect.right > window.innerWidth) {
      linksOutsideScreen.push({ content: link.innerText, top: rect.top });
    } else {
      linksInsideScreen.push({ content: link.innerText, top: rect.top });
    }
  });

  linksInsideScreen.sort((a, b) => a.top - b.top);
  linksOutsideScreen.sort((a, b) => a.top - b.top);

  const linksInsideContent = linksInsideScreen.map((link) => link.content);
  const linksOutsideContent = linksOutsideScreen.map((link) => link.content);

  console.log("OUTSIDE:", linksOutsideContent);

  if (linksInsideScreen.length > 0) {
    const index0Content = linksInsideScreen[0].content;
    console.log("             ");
    console.log("// INDEX 0 //");
    console.log("Index 0 of linksInsideScreen:", index0Content);

    const dataArrayIndex0 = dataArray.findIndex(
      (item) => item.title === index0Content
    );

    if (dataArrayIndex0 !== -1) {
      console.log(
        "Corresponding index and content in dataArray for index 0 ->",
        dataArrayIndex0,
        " | ",
        dataArray[dataArrayIndex0].title
      );

      if (dataArrayIndex0 === 0 && dataArray.length > 0) {
        const lastItemInArray = dataArray[dataArray.length - 1];
        console.log("Last item in dataArray for index 0:", lastItemInArray);

        linksOutsideContent[0] = lastItemInArray.title;
      } else {
        if (dataArrayIndex0 > 0) {
          const itemBeforeCorrespondingIndex = dataArray[dataArrayIndex0 - 1];
          console.log(
            "Item right before the corresponding index for index 0:",
            itemBeforeCorrespondingIndex
          );

          linksOutsideContent[0] = itemBeforeCorrespondingIndex.title;
        } else {
          console.log(
            "No item before the corresponding index for index 0 in dataArray."
          );
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No corresponding index found in dataArray for index 0.");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("No links inside the screen.");
  }

  if (linksInsideScreen.length > 4) {
    const index4Content = linksInsideScreen[4].content;
    console.log("             ");
    console.log("// INDEX 4 //");

    console.log("Index 4 linksInsideScreen ->", index4Content);

    const dataArrayIndex4 = dataArray.findIndex(
      (item) => item.title === index4Content
    );

    if (dataArrayIndex4 !== -1) {
      console.log(
        "Corresponding index and content in dataArray for index 4 ->",
        dataArrayIndex4,
        " | ",
        dataArray[dataArrayIndex4].title
      );

      if (dataArrayIndex4 < dataArray.length - 1) {
        const itemAfterCorrespondingIndex = dataArray[dataArrayIndex4 + 1];

        if (itemAfterCorrespondingIndex && itemAfterCorrespondingIndex.title) {
          const linkOutsideScreen = linksOutsideScreen[4];

          if (linkOutsideScreen) {
            linkOutsideScreen.textContent = itemAfterCorrespondingIndex.title;
            console.log("TEXT CONTENT [4]: ", linkOutsideScreen.textContent);
            console.log(linksOutsideContent);
            //
            const word = document.querySelector(".word");
            word.textContent = itemAfterCorrespondingIndex.title;
          } else {
            console.error("Link outside the screen is undefined.");
          }
        } else {
          console.error("Title is undefined or null in dataArray.");
        }
      } else {
        console.log(
          "No item after the corresponding index for index 4 in dataArray."
        );
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No corresponding index found in dataArray for index 4.");
    }
  } else {
    console.log(
      "Not enough links inside the screen to get content at index 4."
    );
  }
}

function populateLinksWithData() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".palette a");

  links.forEach((link, index) => {
    if (dataArray[index] && dataArray[index].title) {
      link.textContent = dataArray[index].title;
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Load data from data.json
  fetch("data.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      dataArray = data;
      populateLinksWithData(); // Initial population

      setTimeout(() => {
        checkLinksVisibility();
      }, 200);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching data:", error));
});
```

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="palette">
        <div class="color1">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 1 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="color2">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 2 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="color3">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 3 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="color4">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 4 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="color5">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 5 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="color6">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 6 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="color7">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 7 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="color8">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 8 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="color9">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 9 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="color10">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="Asset 14.webp" alt="" />
            <a href="#">Link 10 Fixed</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="active-card-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-up" id="rotateClockwise"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down" id="rotateAntiClockwise"></div>
    <div class="word">Hello world</div>
```

```
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.palette {
  --g: 10px;
  --s: 180px;
  --N: 11;

  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  right: -51%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
}

.palette > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: var(--s) solid green; /* Set color to green */
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(
    calc(50% + var(--g) / 2) 50%,
    calc(50% + var(--g) / 2) 0%,
    calc(86.327% - var(--g) / 2) 0%,
    50% calc(50% - var(--g) / 2)
  );
}

.color1 {
  transform: rotate(-108deg);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: -135px;
  transform: rotate(-250deg);
  font-size: 14px;
}

.text img {
  display: block;
}

.text a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.color2 {
  transform: rotate(-144deg);
}

.color3 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.color4 {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}

.color5 {
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}

.color6 {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}

.color7 {
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}

.color8 {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.color9 {
  transform: rotate(-36deg);
}

.color10 {
  transform: rotate(-72deg);
}

.arrow-up,
.arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
}

.arrow-up:hover {
  border-bottom: 40px solid #909090;
}

.arrow-down:hover {
  border-top: 40px solid #909090;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  top: 30px;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #ccc;
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  bottom: 30px;
  border-top: 40px solid #ccc;
  transform: rotate(8deg);
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.active-card-wrapper {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 0% 100%);
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 18%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 190px;
  height: 195px;
  box-shadow: 32px 32px 39px -33px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
```

I have seen other questions on SO (such as this one: [console.log() works but "textcontent" is not working - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75691680/console-log-works-but-textcontent-is-not-working-javascript)) but none of it solved my problem.

Comment: LinkOutsideScreen is not an html element, it's an object that you created with these properties  `{ content: link.innerText, top: rect.top }`.

Comment: Please make that a [mre]. We surely don't need to understand all that code to see the problem.